# Jackson JSON Parser Keeps Returning Initial Value

Tags: java, json, jackson

My program uses SQL to build a URL to call a web-service, this service will return the following JSON:

```
[{
    "MmisItemNo": "106552",
    "CatalogNo": "UM18840041R",
    "ContractOn": "False"
 }
]
```

What I'm trying to do is strip off the "True" or "False" and use that value to do additional logic.  Here is my code after the SQL builds the URL:
while (rs1.next()){

```
String first = (rs1.getString("PROP_VALUE"));   
String second = (rs1.getString("VEN_ITEM"));

String url = (first.trim()+second.trim());

URL obj = new URL(url);

HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

int  responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " +url);
System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);


BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
    System.out.println(response);

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
LightswitchResponse[] lightswitchResponses = mapper.readValue((response.toString()), LightswitchResponse[].class);
LightswitchResponse lightswitchResponse = lightswitchResponses[0];
System.out.println(lightswitchResponse.ContractOn);
}
} catch (SQLException q) {
logger.error(q);
System.exit(1);
} catch (Exception e) {
logger.error(e,e);
System.exit(1); 
} finally {
}
logger.debug("getlightswitchQuery(): End");
```

Here is my LightswitchResponse class:

```
public class LightswitchResponse {

String MmisItemNo;
String CatalogNo;
boolean ContractOn;

public String getMmisItemNo() {
    return MmisItemNo;
}
public void setMmisItemNo(String mmisItemNo) {
    MmisItemNo = mmisItemNo;
}
public String getCatalogNo() {
    return CatalogNo;
}
public void setCatalogNo(String catalogNo) {
    CatalogNo = catalogNo;
}
public boolean ContractOn() {
    return ContractOn;
}
public void setContractOn(boolean contractOn) {
    ContractOn = contractOn;
}

}
```

My problem is that when I print my results = > ContractOn just returns false for every single line record/json regardless if its True or False.

For Example:

```
Response Code : 200
[{"MmisItemNo":"106552","CatalogNo":"UM18840041R","ContractOn":"False"}]
false

Response Code : 200
[{"MmisItemNo":"164065","CatalogNo":"UM005979091RH","ContractOn":"True"}]
false
```

I was originally thinking that it was something in my buffer not clearing, but after digging into it more, I don't think that's the case.  Any idea what might be causing this issue of repeated false regardless of the string response?

Answer (score 0):

The main trouble here is that you are using non-standard Java naming conventions for your JSON.

Annotating your LightswitchResponse as follows will work:

```
public static class LightswitchResponse {

    String MmisItemNo;
    String CatalogNo;
    boolean ContractOn;

    public String getMmisItemNo() {
        return MmisItemNo;
    }

    @JsonProperty("MmisItemNo")
    public void setMmisItemNo(String mmisItemNo) {
        MmisItemNo = mmisItemNo;
    }
    public String getCatalogNo() {
        return CatalogNo;
    }

    @JsonProperty("CatalogNo")
    public void setCatalogNo(String catalogNo) {
        CatalogNo = catalogNo;
    }

    public boolean ContractOn() {
        return ContractOn;
    }

    @JsonProperty("ContractOn")
    public void setContractOn(boolean contractOn) {
        ContractOn = contractOn;
    }

}
```

The following test passes OK:

```
@Test
public void testDeserializeBoolean() throws IOException{
    final String test = "[{\"MmisItemNo\": \"106552\",\"CatalogNo\": \"UM18840041R\",\"ContractOn\": \"False\"}," +
            "{\"MmisItemNo\": \"106552\",\"CatalogNo\": \"UM18840041R\",\"ContractOn\": \"True\"}]";
    final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    LightswitchResponse[] resp = objectMapper.readValue(test
            ,
            LightswitchResponse[].class);
    Assert.assertEquals(false, resp[0].ContractOn());
    Assert.assertEquals(true, resp[1].ContractOn());
}
```